# Entity Framework 4.3.1 Eager Loading Multiple Levels of Child Objects With Filter

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, parent-child, eager-loading

I'm using EF 4.3.1 and I'm doing my first implementation of Code First and testing the data. Here's my setup trying to implement eager loading.

```
public class Model 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ModelArchive> ModelArchives { get; set; }
}

public class ModelArchive 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to only select the Options where Deleted == false in my query. So far I'm coming up empty or it results in an exception when running the query.

Here's my current query:

```
using (var db = new ModelContainer())
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var model = db.Models.Where(m => m.Id == 3)
                  .Include(m => m.ModelArchives.Select(o => o.Option).Where(o => o.Deleted == false));
}
```

Exception: Message = "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.\r\nParameter name: path"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load filtered data with Entity Framework. Navigation properties either contain all related entities, or none of them.

Consider to do manual join and return anonymous objects with not deleted options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
using (var db = new ModelContainer())
{
//db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var model = db.Models.Where(m => m.Id == 3 && m.ModelArchives.Option.Deleted==false)
              .Include(m => m.ModelArchives.Option);
}
```

You can use generic function to get the data

```
 public  List<T> IncludeMultipleWithWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> itemWithIncludes = dbContext.Set<T>() as IQueryable<T>;
        try
        {
            if (includes != null)
            {
                itemWithIncludes = includes.Aggregate(itemWithIncludes,
                          (current, include) => current.Include(include)).Where(predicate);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally { }
        return itemWithIncludes.ToList();

    }
```

your calling function just need to passing the parameter like

```
 Expression<Func<Models, bool>> whereCond1 =  (m) => m.Id == 3 && m.ModelArchives.Option.Deleted==false;
 Expression<Func<Models, object>>[] includeMulti = { m => m.ModelArchives.Option };
```

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in disabling lazyloading.
But then you have to filter the navigation property in a subquery, and EF will magically attach it to your main query. Here is something that should work

```
using (var db = new ModelContainer())
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var filteredModelArchives = db.ModelArchives.Select(o => o.Option).Where(o => o.Deleted == false).Include("Options");

    var model = db.Models.Where(m => m.Id == 3);
}
```